# Bad: with Class full-left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Everyone I'm new in this world, im making course to make a web site, when I need to make float  in class, I use class="pull-left" , in this course we are using bootstrap, but when I need separeted this objects with "pull-left" it's not working, really I don't Know what is my mistake, thaks for support

```
<title> Pizeria Palermo </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles3.css">
```

```
<header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="indexs3.html" class="float">
                    <div id="logo-img">  </div>
                </a>

              
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="indexs3.html" > <h1>Pialermo</h1></a>

                    </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
   
</header>
```

Comment: Hello. Please add your custom css here that deals with the problem. And tell me which version of the bootstrap. Read pls - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many ways to do this but simply we set class to both div **float-left**.
2. navbar-header to apply css like **display: flex, justify-content: flex-start, align-items: center;**

i hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use "justify-content-left" or "align-self-left" property of Bootstrap 4